# Codeigniter pagination not showing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried codeigniter pagination and so far the pagination not seems to be working? I refered many previous answers but was not helpful.Any help would be appreciated.I have posted my controller,model and view page .Hope someone helps in rectify the error ..i refered other sites to but none of its working. Only the data gets displayed

Controller :

```
class Events extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
         $this->load->model("admin_model");
         $this->load->model("Home_model");
              $this->load->model("Banners_model");
       $this->load->library('Pagination');
    }
public function index($page = 1){
       //$data['title'] = "All Events"; 
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = "All Events";
        $where = array();
        $orderby = array('ban.bId', 'desc');
        $join = array();
        $groupby = array();
        $like = array();
        $or_like = array();
        $or_where = array();
        $where_in = array();
        $where_not = array();
        $where = array('ban.act' =>0,'ban.categoryid' =>9,'ban.status' => 1);
        //$or_where['ban.act'] = 0;
        $data['filterevents'] = $get = $this->input->get();
        $select = ('ban.*');

        $all = $this->Home_model->geteventdetail($where, $orderby, $select, $join, "", "", "", "", $like, $or_like, $or_where, $where_in, $where_not);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
        if (!empty($all)) {
            $config['total_rows'] = count($all);
        } else {
            $config['total_rows'] = 0;
        }
        $config["uri_segment"] = "3";
        $limit = 5;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $limit;
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'Events/index';
        $config["cur_page"] = $page;
        if (isset($get['sel']) && !empty($get['sel'])) {
           $config["per_page"] = $get['sel'];
        } else {
           $config["per_page"] = $this->config->item('per_page');
        }
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
        $data["events"] = $this->Home_model->geteventdetail($where, $orderby, $select, $join, $groupby, $limit, $offset, "", $like, $or_like, $or_where, $where_in, $where_not);
         //$data['events'] = $this->Home_model->Geteventdetailsdata();
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
          // $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
        load_view_frond_template('home/events', $data, $this);
        echo $this->template->render("", true);
    }
```

Model :

```
function geteventdetail($where = array(), $orderby = array(), $select = "", $join = array(), $group_by = "", $limit = "", $offset = 0, $row = false, $like = array(), $or_like = array(), $or_where = array(), $where_in = array(), $where_not = array()) {
        $this->db->select($select);
        $this->db->from('hel_banners as ban');
        if (is_array($join) && !empty($join)) {
            foreach ($join as $k => $v) {
                if (is_array($v))
                    $this->db->join($k, $v[0], $v[1]);
                else
                    $this->db->join($k, $v);
            }
        }
        if (is_array($where_in) && !empty($where_in)) {
            foreach ($where_in as $k => $v) {
                if (is_array($v))
                    $this->db->where_in($k, $v);
                else
                    $this->db->where_in($k, $v);
            }
        }
        if (is_array($where_not) && !empty($where_not)) {
            foreach ($where_not as $k => $v) {
                if (is_array($v))
                    $this->db->where_not_in($k, $v);
                else
                    $this->db->where_not_in($k, $v);
            }
        }
        if (is_array($where)) {
            if (!empty($where))
                $this->db->where($where);
        } elseif ($where != "") {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        if (is_array($or_where)) {
            if (!empty($or_where))
                $this->db->or_where($or_where);
        } elseif ($or_where != "") {
            $this->db->where($or_where);
        }
        if (is_array($like)) {
            if (!empty($like)) {
                $this->db->like($like);
                $this->db->or_like($or_like);
            }
        } elseif ($like != "") {
            $this->db->like($like);
        }

        if (is_array($orderby) && !empty($orderby)) {
            foreach ($orderby as $k => $v) {
                $this->db->order_by($k, $v);
            }
        }
        if ($group_by)
            $this->db->group_by($group_by);
        if ((int) $limit != 0)
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            if (!$row)
                return $query->result();
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
```

Views:

```
                       <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: 20px;padding-top: 20px;border: 1px solid #abd520;">      
                                <?php 

                                foreach ($events as $eve)

                                    { ?>
                                <div class="entry-meta mb-10" style="padding-top: 20px;">

                                      <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <?php 
                                       $timestamp = strtotime($eve->created_date);
                                          $new_date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
                                          echo $new_date;
                                        ?>

                                </div>
                                <div class="port-info mt-20 mb-20">
                                    <p style="text-align:justify;">
                                    <h4> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Events/event_view/<?php echo $eve->bId;?>"><?php echo $eve->bannersTitle; ?></a></h4><br>
                                    <p><?php echo substr($eve->content, 0, 150); ?> ....<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Events/event_view/<?php echo $eve->bId;?>">Read More</a></p>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                  <hr style="color:black;">
                                <?php } ?>

                            </div>      

                        <!--blog comment -->
                        <div id="pagination">
<ul class="tsc_pagination">
 <p><!-- Show pagination links -->
<?php 
echo "". $links."";
 ?></p>

            </div>
```

When i replace this line in controller ,only one record gets shown and pagination appears

```
if (isset($get['sel']) && !empty($get['sel'])) {
           $config["per_page"] = $get['sel'];
        } else {
           $config["per_page"] = $this->config->item('per_page');
        }
```

TO

```
if (isset($get['sel']) && !empty($get['sel'])) {
           $config["per_page"] = 1;
        } else {
           $config["per_page"] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: do you get any error? Have you loaded the pagination library? `$this->load->library('pagination');`

Comment: Yes i Have loaded

Comment: Please check if this affect the visibility of pagination `<ul class="tsc_pagination">`, is not closed. Check the page source code in the browser. Your code should work

Comment: pagination works but when i click on next button same page showing @vaslienicusor

Comment: Remove this line from your controller $config[‘uri_segment’] = 3;

The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($get['sel']) && !empty($get['sel'])) {
           $config["per_page"] = $get['sel'];
        } else {
           $config["per_page"] = $this->config->item('per_page');
        }
```

change it to

```
$config["per_page"] = (isset($get['sel']) && is_numeric($get['sel']) )?$get['sel']:10;
```

or

```
$config["per_page"] = (isset($get['sel']) && is_numeric($get['sel']) )?$get['sel']:($this->config->item('per_page') && is_numeric($this->config->item('per_page')))?$this->config->item('per_page'):10;
```

and if you have autoload library than load library before

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

replace

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

to

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

you are using get method. so if you have selected any of option and you have get url .. base url for config effect

after

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'Events/index';
```

add

```
if(isset($_GET))
            {
                $config['first_url']        = $config['base_url'].'/1'.'?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");    
            }
```

Comment: share me your code on git and shere your link . upload sql and only mvc you are getting trouble

Comment: k i will send u

Comment: pagination works but when i click on next button same page showing @Mashih Ansaro